# Track simulation jittering & Instability

Tags: rigging, physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I will start by posting a video illustrating the issue:
[Track issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XybdbpwTONo)

To put the issue in words; the tracks will randomly jitter along their respective axis. This is not limited to the one area shown in the video but also occurs when the track runs along the top of the roadwheels.
I may be wrong but I *think* that this may be due to some sort of instant change in acceleration which happens to one track; resulting in a chain reaction. The rotation and scale of every object is applied. If anyone has insight on what I could do to mitigate this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

***Rig details vvv***

My rig consists of 2 main parts, one being the actual tracks and the other being the roadwheels. The tracks are all rigid bodies with each being connected to the next via a hinge constraint.
[image: Tracks]

The second part(the wheels) are also rigid bodies. Each of the wheels has a generic spring constraint. The 5 roadwheels also have a constraint to limit their distance from the suspension.
[image: Generic Spring constraint for the 5 roadwheels]

The drive wheel has a motor constraint along with a the generic spring constraint (which does not have springs enabled) and the tensioning wheel towards the front is the same as the drive wheel minus the motor constraint.

Here is a file which contains the rig. One side of tracks is a different size from the other as I was messing around trying to find solutions (It doesnt effect anything).

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Decreased the solver iterations from 100 to 50. Eliminated the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)